# Idiomatic way to register generic spring beans in beanFactory

Tags: spring

Our team has small spring library. Customer should configure DSL bean with generic,
and our library parse DSL bean and creates a lot of platform beans with same generic.

Simple example below:

Customer creates `DslConfig<String>`, and `RegisteredPlatformBeanClass<String>` should be registred by our library.

```java
// customer creates
@Bean
DslConfig<String> dslConfig() {
return new DslConfig<>();
}

// should be registred
@Bean
String consumePlatformBean(RegisteredPlatformBeanClass<String> registeredBeanClass) {
System.out.println("Ohhh i was created with string generic!");

return "consumed!";
}
```

Currently, we register such beans with BeanFactoryPostProcessor.

Simple example is below

```java
@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    final String[] beanNames = beanFactory
        .getBeanNamesForType(DslConfig.class, false, false);
    final DefaultListableBeanFactory defaultListableBeanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory;

    for (String beanName: beanNames) {

        final ParameterizedType springConfigurationMethodGeneric = getGenericType(beanFactory, beanName);

        final RootBeanDefinition registeredBean =
            (RootBeanDefinition) BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(RegisteredPlatformBeanClass.class)
            .getBeanDefinition();

        final Class << ? > dslType = (Class << ? > ) springConfigurationMethodGeneric.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        registeredBean.setTargetType(
            ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(
                RegisteredPlatformBeanClass.class,
                dslType
            )
        );
        defaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(beanName + "_registered", registeredBean);
    }
}
```

Is it correct way to register beans in such scenarios using `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` or we should use another way?
Sadly, but we can't find any example or recomendation in spring reference documentation,